# Flutter web app not setting up with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

It has been 3 weeks since I have been trying to set up firebase with a flutter web app. I have been following tutorials all over the internet but none of them have been able to help me. Every time I get the same errors.

This is my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="quiz_app_4">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>quiz_app_4</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.8/firebase-analytics.js";
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
    import { } from 'firebase/auth';
    import { } from 'firebase/database';
  
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "...",
      projectId: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
      messagingSenderId: "...",
      appId: "...",
      measurementId: "..."
    };
  
    // Initialize Firebase
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>

  <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
  <script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {
              // No active web worker and we have installed or are installing
              // one for the first time. Simply wait for it to activate.
              waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {
              // When the app updates the serviceWorkerVersion changes, so we
              // need to ask the service worker to update.
              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {
              // Existing service worker is still good.
              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });

        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {
      loadMainDartJs();
    }
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

These are my pubspec.yaml dependencies.

```
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

  firebase_core: ^1.13.1
  firebase_database: ^9.0.8
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.9
  # firebase_core_web: ^1.6.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
...
```

These are the errors I get.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'http' in 'package:http/http.dart'. 
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:10:8: Error: Not found:
'package:http/http.dart'
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
       ^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:48:14: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    getPath: allowInterop(strategy.getPath),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:49:15: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    getState: allowInterop(strategy.getState),
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:50:26: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    addPopStateListener: allowInterop(strategy.addPopStateListener),
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:51:25: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    prepareExternalUrl: allowInterop(strategy.prepareExternalUrl),
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:52:16: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    pushState: allowInterop(strategy.pushState),
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:53:19: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    replaceState: allowInterop(strategy.replaceState),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:54:9: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    go: allowInterop(strategy.go),
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:48:15: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.  if (js_util.getProperty(e, 'name') == 'FirebaseError') {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:49:20: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.    return js_util.getProperty(e, 'code') ?? '';
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:61:15: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.  if (js_util.getProperty(e, 'name') == 'FirebaseError') {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:62:30: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.    String rawCode = js_util.getProperty(e, 'code');
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:64:30: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.    String message = js_util.getProperty(e, 'message') ?? '';
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:36:12: Error: The getter 'context' isn't  
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
    return context['require'] != null;
           ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:45:12: Error: The getter 'context' isn't  
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
    return context['flutterfire_web_sdk_version'] ??
           ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:61:7: Error: 'JsObject' isn't a type.     
      JsObject ignored =
      ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:62:11: Error: The getter 'JsObject' isn't 
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'JsObject'.
          JsObject.fromBrowserObject(context['flutterfire_ignore_scripts']);
          ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:62:38: Error: The getter 'context' isn't  
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
          JsObject.fromBrowserObject(context['flutterfire_ignore_scripts']);
                                     ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:79:5: Error: 'ScriptElement' isn't a type.    ScriptElement script = ScriptElement();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:79:28: Error: The method 'ScriptElement'  
isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ScriptElement'.
    ScriptElement script = ScriptElement();
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:83:12: Error: The getter 'document' isn't 
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'document'.
    assert(document.head != null);
           ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:84:5: Error: The getter 'document' isn't  
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'document'.
    document.head!.append(script);
    ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:93:9: Error: The getter 'context' isn't
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
    if (context['firebase'] != null) {
        ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:134:5: Error: 'JsObject' isn't a type.    
    JsObject require = JsObject.fromBrowserObject(context['require']);
    ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:126:9: Error: The getter 'context' isn't  
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
    if (context['firebase'] != null) {
        ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:134:24: Error: The getter 'JsObject' isn'tdefined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'JsObject'.
    JsObject require = JsObject.fromBrowserObject(context['require']);
                       ^^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:134:51: Error: The getter 'context' isn't 
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
    JsObject require = JsObject.fromBrowserObject(context['require']);
                                                  ^^^^^^^
../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart:136:7: Error: The getter 'JsObject' isn't 
defined for the class 'FirebaseCoreWeb'.
 - 'FirebaseCoreWeb' is from 'package:firebase_core_web/firebase_core_web.dart'
 ('../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.1/lib/firebase_core_web.dart').
...


(package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:164:65)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #2      FrontendCompiler.writeJavascriptBundle (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:665:32)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:573:9)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #4      listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1154:11)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
    Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...             26.1s
    Failed to compile application.
```

Adding http to my dependencies eliminates

```
Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'http' in 'package:http/http.dart'.
```

I need only the firebase authentication and firebase realtime database for my project.

I am new to flutter and have already built my app and it works fine on android but I need it as a web app to host it on a server.

It would really make my life alot easier if anyone helped me.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reinstalling flutter fixed my issue.

Navigate to the folder where your android-sdk, flutter, and projects reside.

Delete the flutter folder.

Download flutter zip from https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

**Extract it to the same folder from where you deleted your previous flutter folder.**

You are good to go!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a **flutter clean**? your code looks pretty straightforward. The only thing I spotted was that in your **Firebase.initializeApp** you are not providing the **options** properties you get from Firebase:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  // pass the options from the Firebase SDK configuration
  options: const FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "XXX",
      authDomain: "XXX",
      databaseURL: "XXX",
      projectId: "XXX",
      storageBucket: "XXX",
      messagingSenderId: "XXX",
      appId: "XXX"
    ));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Still the same errors. Should I reinstall flutter?

Answer (score 0):

This setup has worked for me when adding **Web** platform to a gigantic 2-year-old **Flutter** project which heavily uses **Firebase** (functions, analytics, etc).

- I had my libraries imported in 'pubspec.yaml'
- I had initialised the project like all the flutter docs recommend

The drama happened in the index.html. In different docs there was a combination of new and old ways of doing things: or rather the way you would do firebase web in a simple Web project, vs. how you would make Web work in a **Flutter Web project with Firebase.** Afted days of searching... Turned out that I was not meant to use the most recent firebasejs. (one of the errors hinted me to it).

**Basically the newest firebasejs/9.x.x broke everything, with weird mysterious errors, but moving to firebasejs/8.10.1 suddently everything works.**

Fixes to my mistakes:

- put these in  tag
- Do NOT import libraries with CDN import tags like `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs...`
- import libraries in a `<script type="module">` tag with the new, empty bracket { }, ot by specifying which parts of each library
- import `firebase-app.js` first
- no need for `const firebaseConfig = {...}` or for `const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

No Need for This:

```
// script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

// script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

// script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

// script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

But this is important:

```
import {  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js";

import {  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js";

import {  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-functions.js";

import {  } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-analytics.js";
</script>

<script>
```

And no Need for This:

```
//const firebaseConfig = {...};

//const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//const db = getFirestore(app);

</script>

//then rest of the Body tag
```